# How to build regex for this in data annotations?

Tags: c#, regex

I am doing data annotation validations... I need to validate a property that should contain only the following words: "Active" or "Termination". Can it be done using regular expressions? Because now I have separate custom class for that like below.

```
Class Status

{

Override IsValid()

{

if (!(value.ToString().ToUpper() == "ACTIVE" || value.ToString().ToUpper() == "TERMINATION"))

return err;

}

}
```

Comment: Why do you need regular expressions if you just want to check if a string equals another?

Comment: Because then he can use built in RegularExpression Data Annotation instead of creating a custom one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually create a generic `Custom Validator`, if you are interested instead of creating a separate `class` as mentioned in your OP.

Following code shows how to create a custom Validator.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EqualsToTextAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    #region Instance Fields

    private readonly string[] textToCompare;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public EqualsToTextAttribute(string[] textToCompare)
    {
        this.textToCompare = textToCompare;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected Methods

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (this.textToCompare.Any(text => string.Equals(value.ToString(), text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Below code shows how to use the custom data annotation attribute:

```
    [EqualsToText(new[] { "Active", "Termination" })]
    public string TestString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.testString;
        }
        set
        {
            //This is to test the validation. Can be removed if you are using the control which applies Validation attributes automatically, e.g. DataGrid
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "TestString" }); 
            this.testString = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match either of those strings case insensitive:

```
/^Active|Termination$/i
```

Comment: Actually, the correct regular expression should be `^(active|termination)$`. The forward slash "quotes" aren't part of the **C#** language: that's Perl, PHP and the like. Further, your original `^active|termination$` will be parsed as if it were written `(^active)|(termination$)`, that is "'active' at start-of-line **or** 'termination' at end-of-line" . . . Rather than " start of line, followed by one of 'active' or 'termination', followed by end of line.